# Getting a postId for many users on FirebaseFirestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a specific post for all the users that have a specific postId. I do not care who the user is, I only care about whether they have a specific post in their collection of posts. I use the following command, but it does NOT work.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('savedPosts').doc(postId).get().then((doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    doc.reference.delete();
  }
});
```

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks

Below you can see 2 pictures of how my database is structured:
[Database pic #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IvTw.png)

[Database pic #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QKsH.png)

Comment: Can you please share what your database structure looks like? Also the `.doc()` is empty and will result in an error. You must specify the doc ID.

Comment: Hello! I edited my post to explicitly show what my database looks like. What I am trying to do is get all the userIds of the users that have saved a specific post (postId) and then erase that post from the database. How would you do that?

Comment: We really need to see your structure to understand the question and post a correct answer. Please update the question with a snippet of your structure.

Comment: Sounds good! I just added 2 pictures of my database in the post. Please let me know

Comment: In the future and once you have enough rep, please include images in the question. If the links break, future readers wont be able to see the structure which would invalidate the question. As far as a solution goes, I am going to recommend you change your structure; there are collections inside collections and while it can be made to work, breaking those out will make the queries a LOT simpler. Also, you can't query for a documentID, which is what I think you're doing. The query will need to be on a field *inside* the document.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the input. What exactly do you mean by "you can't query for a documentID, which is what I think you're doing. The query will need to be on a field inside the document" ? What solution do see for that?

Comment: You can think of Firestore as a dictionary of key: value pairs. Keys (the documentID) must be unique, and you can't query for a key. Thinking through that a bit, if you *know* the key, you wouldn't need to query for it, right? Queries are designed to look for data *within* a document - those are known as *fields* and you CAN query on fields. It may help to review the Getting Started Guide [Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to better understand that process. Also when replying to someone precede their name with an at sign, like @Jay to get their attention.